# Move cursor up or down multiple lines while preserving column

Tags: motion

I find it convenient to move by multiple lines for quickly scrolling up/down:

```lisp
;; replaces forward-sentence
(global-set-key (kbd "M-e")
                (lambda () (interactive) (next-line 3)))

;; replaces backward-sentence
(global-set-key (kbd "M-a")
                (lambda () (interactive) (previous-line 3)))
```

However, this gives doesn't save the column of the cursor after you switch directions.  For example, suppose a buffer contains the following:

```
This is line 1. 
This is line 2.
This is line 3.

This is line 5.
```

Put your cursor on the "1" in the first line, then press C-n 3 times, then press C-p 3 times. You should find that you end up back on the "1".

Now, define M-e and M-a using the above keyboard shortcuts. Try putting your cursor on the "1", press M-e *once*, then M-a *once*.  Your cursor ends up at the *beginning* of the first line! (Tested on Emacs 24.5.1).

How can you move multiple lines in one keypress and preserve the column after switching directions? I tried replacing `next-line` with `forward-line`... no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original poster may wish to use the universal-argument to move N lines up or down -- e.g., `C-u 3 up` and `C-u 3 down`; or `C-3 up` and `C-3 down`.

Internal functions within `simple.el` (relating to `next-line` and `previous-line`) check the value of the *variable* `last-command`.  Since the original poster created new `lambda` functions attached to keyboard shortcuts, it is necessary to expressly set the value of `this-command` -- which becomes `last-command` towards the end of the current command loop.

```lisp
;; replaces forward-sentence
(global-set-key (kbd "M-e")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (setq this-command 'next-line)
    (next-line 3)))

;; replaces backward-sentence
(global-set-key (kbd "M-a")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (setq this-command 'previous-line)
    (previous-line 3)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like `highline.el` is interfering with this approach.  It's probably a bug in that package.

To answer your question: typing `C-u 3 down` is tedious if I want to quickly scroll down to a line that's, say, 30 lines down from the current cursor position.